# Car steering issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm following [this tutorial](http://youtu.be/a6LgepzXIjw?list=PL67XFC3MYQ6K0PXSad15xFrhxNL76r4Te) using [this model](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model.html?id=uf8040ff1-1b58-459a-b488-632cfb5f4fa2). I've set up the front wheels to rotate across the Y axis so they look like they are steering. However, the Left Front "NSF" wheel isn't rotating where I'd like it to. It seems to be parrell with the Front Right "OSF" and just moving backwards and forwards whilst rotating. 
Here is my code so far :

```
pragma strict
var wheelNSF : WheelCollider;
var wheelNSR : WheelCollider;
var wheelOSF : WheelCollider;
var wheelOSR : WheelCollider;
var maxTorque : float = 50;
;
var wheelNSFTransform : Transform;
var wheelNSRTransform : Transform;
var wheelOSFTransform : Transform;
var wheelOSRTransform : Transform;



function Start () {
rigidbody.centerOfMass.y = -0.9;
}

function FixedUpdate () {
wheelOSR.motorTorque = maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
wheelNSR.motorTorque = maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
wheelOSF.steerAngle = 10 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
wheelNSF.steerAngle = 10 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}

function Update(){
wheelNSFTransform.Rotate(wheelNSF.rpm/60*360*Time.deltaTime,0,0);
wheelNSRTransform.Rotate(wheelNSR.rpm/60*360*Time.deltaTime,0,0);
wheelOSFTransform.Rotate(wheelOSF.rpm/60*360*Time.deltaTime,0,0);
wheelOSRTransform.Rotate(wheelOSR.rpm/60*360*Time.deltaTime,0,0);
wheelOSFTransform.localEulerAngles.y = wheelOSF.steerAngle - wheelOSFTransform.localEulerAngles.z;

wheelNSFTransform.localEulerAngles.y = wheelNSF.steerAngle - wheelNSFTransform.localEulerAngles.z;
}
```

Is it a model issue? Or am I coding incorrect?

Pictures to show whats happening :[image]

Comment: What does their hierarchy look like? Is one parented to the other?

Comment: If you zoom in on the hierarchy in the picture, they're under the "WheelModels"

Comment: If the wheels share a parent, they'll rotate relative to that parent. You may need to attach each wheel to a distinct pivot point, so that they'll rotate around those.

Comment: I've removed them from the parent, and complete from the model, and I'm still getting the same issue. Do you think the pivot set in the modelling software is to blame?